# Name objects in for loop

Tags: r, loops, object

I have this `for` loop for processing (correction) some spectral data:

```
names_list <- ls(pattern="s+\\d") # the names of the uncorrected spectra are s01, s02, s02 etc...
c <- mget(ls(pattern="s+\\d"))

for (file in c) {
  
  process <- process_spec(file,
               active = TRUE,
               adj_intens = FALSE,
               adj_intens_args = list(type = "none"),
              conform_spec = TRUE,
              conform_spec_args = list(range = FTIR_lib$wavenumber, res = 5, type = "interp"),
              etc...)
  
  names <- paste0("corr_", names_list)
  
  assign(names, process, envir = .GlobalEnv) # OPTION 1 
  list2env(as.list(setNames(names, process)), envir = .GlobalEnv) # OPTION 2 
  
}
```

I would like to apply this correction function (`process_spec()`) in a loop to all of my spectra (s01, s02, s03 etc.) and name these corrected objects in the Global Environment as: corr_s01, corr_s02, etc...

Option 1 is not working.

Option 2 creates "values", not objects.

Example of uncorrected spectral object:

```
str(s01)
List of 3
 $ wavenumber: num [1:7468] 400 401 401 402 402 ...
 $ spectra   :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    7468 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ intensity: num [1:7468] 0.46 0.453 0.446 0.442 0.438 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ metadata  :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ x        : int 1
  ..$ y        : int 1
  ..$ file_name: chr "s01"
  ..$ file_id  : chr "Nahal_Rahaf_2"
  ..$ col_id   : chr "intensity"
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "OpenSpecy" "list"
```

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It doesn't look like you are subsetting `names_list` at all in the loop so there's no way for it to know which name to use and it will use the same values every iteration. Also in general its usually easier to avoid creating separate variables and just collecting everything in a named list you can more easily create with `lapply` than a loop

Comment: I cannot use `name_list` since this is a list and `process_spec()` only takes OpenSpecy objects, that is why I use `c`.

Comment: But you use `names_list` in `names <- paste0("corr_", names_list)` when you try to pick the name of the variable. That will result in a vector (presumably since we can't actually run and test the code).

Comment: I would also avoid naming objects 'c' since 'c()' is a fairly core R function it can have unintended consequences.

Comment: @MrFlick I had to because if I use `names <- paste0("corr_", c)` it gives me this error:  `Error in assign(names, process, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
In addition: Warning message:
In assign(names, process, envir = .GlobalEnv) :
  only the first element is used as variable name`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I consider this cargo cult advice. Name clashes are unavoidable, and can be dealt with (e.g. by limiting the scope of names as much as possible, which is good practice anyway). Naming an object `c` — *if that name makes sense in context!* — is not an issue and should not be discouraged.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen what unintended consequences? R interpreter will never get confused between `c` and `c()`

Comment: Fair - for people who know what they are doing it holds no fears, but I still think it's a good habit to be in to avoid such names unless, as you say, they make sense in a specific context.

Comment: @Valentina I did not mean to imply that was the solution, I was trying to help you understand where the problem is. If you are iterating over object values, there's no way to access their names. Instead, if you iterate over the names, you can get the value from that name in each iteration of that loop. But again, this is generally an inefficient strategy in R. It's better to keep related values in a list and apply transformations to that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R it is generally not a good idea to make a bunch of named global variables following a particular pattern (like corr_sN), but instead to just use a list.

`corrList = lapply(c, function(file) process_spec(file, ...))`

Replace `...` with all the arguments to `process_spec`.

The objects will then be accessible by index `corrList[[i]]`

Comment: You don’t need to use an anonymous function here, `lapply` allows specifying further arguments directly in-line: `lapply(c, process_spec, …)`. Whether that’s more readable than inserting an anonymous function, alas, is somewhat subjective.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm lazy and do it that way for tab code completion of argument names 8)

Comment: That’s not a bad reason, to be honest. Future versions of R (and the surrounding tooling) potentially *might* get better at this with [a new addition to the language that is currently being discussed](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14354).